# Please remove the [error] tag from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I have just seen a question with the ["error" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) on it. This tag does not seem to add anything to questions.

What is its use?

Should `[error]` be deleted and added to the list of prohibited tags?

Comment: Hey, I just got a badge for it!  Admittedly I chuckled.  I have answered several questions about mysterious error codes.  Five votes per answer on average, a very uncommon luxury for me.

Answer (score 9):

It's a meta-tag, and should be removed.

Reasoning:

- It doesn't reasonably stand on its own
  (it doesn't describe a technology, feature or methodology)

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I am still seeing questions with this tag (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6295916/265570)  Are these meta tags making a comeback?

Answer (score 0):

It's there so people can search specifically for an "error" that they're dealing with, and not get other kinds of posts.